# How much UK income tax is collected from each income tax band?

Tags: taxation, statistics

How much of the 208 billion Income Tax receipts in [this 2020 budget policy paper](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/budget-2020-documents/budget-2020) is coming from each of the three ([Basic rate, Higher rate & Additional rate](https://www.gov.uk/income-tax-rates)) tax bands?

[image]

Comment: You might want to look at https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics/income-tax-liabilities-by-income-range and https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics/income-tax-liabilities-by-taxpayers-marginal-rate If you want more, see https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/income-tax-statistics-and-distributions

Comment: @Henry : I already have, can't find what I want, I wouldn't have asked here if I could.

Comment: @Henry : I don't do pdf downloads anyway, always get garbage my end when I do, I see a couple of those are MS excel, chances are their the latest excel & I refuse to pay MSoft for the new one when I have the old one so I can't download them either.

Comment: @Henry : I might add that given the links I provided in the question you must have known I'd already been all over the government website (the ONS too as it happens) ;)

Comment: So in what way does Table 2.6 in my links fail to give an answer to your question?

Comment: @Henry : So in what way did you not understand any of this *"always get garbage my end when I do, I see a couple of those are MS excel, chances are their the latest excel & I refuse to pay MSoft for the new one when I have the old one so I can't download them either"* all I get is garbage.

Comment: That was a bit of a rant.  I can read the Excel .xlsx files happily with MS Office Home and Student 2013.  I would expect Libre Office and similar suites to work too.  If all else fails, there are pdf tables you can read

Comment: @Henry : Well good for you, you've software that opens those, I don't, & I'd already told you that hadn't I.